# How do I check if a user has administrator permission with discord-oauth2-api?

Tags: discord

I am making a web panel for my discord bot with a module called discord-oauth2-api and I can get my perms in the servers as permission code like this: 453223243328 but I don't know what does change if a user has administrator in this code so I can't check if a user has administrator.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what i found the code: 2147483647 under the voice of "permissions" means that the user in the server has "Administrator" permission (the code can even mean the user is the owner of the server).

You can even find if the user is admin with the voice: "permissions_new" which is: 4398046511103.
Thats what i've found, if you what to know more theres a guide from discord for all the values https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/permissions